# How to refresh ASP .NET MVC page when hitting browser back button

Tags: javascript, .net, browser, asp.net-mvc-5, page-refresh

I just found that when I click  browser back button on any ASP .NET MVC page nothing happens and page is not going be updated. And only if you click F5 it will be updated only.

The main problem that I do some changes of DOM of the page i.e. add table rows select radio-buttons and etc and when I go back to page by hitting browser back button I have see no changes.

How it can be resolved for ASP .NET MVC 5?

Thank for any clue...

P.S. I have read http://forums.asp.net/t/1304752.aspx?how+to+refresh+page+when+hitting+back+button but it does not help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9009858/2563028

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is a proper solution http://dotscrapbook.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/handling-a-browser-back-button-press-with-mvc/.

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")] 
public ActionResult MyView()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: You made my day! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { location.reload(); };
```

Comment: Does window.onbeforeunload = function() { alert('for test'); };  this function fire?