# Javascript state is saved when using back button to get to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Firefox, and I have noticed something interesting while working on my website. One page has a table of information, but also maintains Javascript variables indicating the table's contents so it can look up information more easily.

When I navigate away from the page by typing in a URL, then hit the back button to return, I have noticed that the page seems to retain its state. The table still has the same contents as when I left, and further interactions with the page indicate that the Javascript variables have maintained their values as well.

I had assumed that my `$(document).ready();` functions would run again when the back button was hit, but this is clearly not the case as I wrote those functions to ensure the page is its initial state, regardless of the page's current content.

I think it is perfectly acceptable for the page to be restored this way as long as I can depend on the page being restored properly. If instead, the page is restored to its initial state, that would be acceptable as well.

Is it safe to rely on this behavior? Would I be better off using something like `onunload` to ensure that the page's state is not saved? Should I just assume the browser will do things properly?

I would say that my website's state is defined by the HTML on the page and the contents of Javascript variables. It uses AJAX (or I guess technically [AJAJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAJ)) to interact with PHP pages, but all interactions are discrete transactions. The only state/session needed by the server are login authentication cookies, which should be unaffected by this.

Comment: Check this link about preserving page state on back button : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009858/preserve-page-state-for-revisiting-using-browser-back-button

Comment: Interesting, but they seem to be experiencing the opposite issue. The accepted answer indicates that what I am seeing should never happen (which is actually what I expected).

Comment: Dear, this is the normal cache system of Chrome or Firefox. when you go backward it is because you forgot something, so you recover the page like you let it right before. Text filled, etc.

Comment: Maybe, MAYBE, setting an header like : `header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');` would do the job to remove the cache.

Comment: @AlexisPaques: this is indeed a nice feature, however it should not be relied upon. I'm curious what happens if a clear cache is done before getting back to the page...

Comment: Then nothing is saved, if you clear the cache, chrome/Firefox will load it again from zero !

Comment: It looks like firefox keep variable states on back button, but I have to test it with different browsers!

Comment: Yeah, just tried it, and it loads the page from scratch, rerunning `$(document).ready();` functions. So is it safe to rely on then? Either it will load it all perfectly or else reload it from scratch?

Comment: Can you try with IE or Chrome?

Comment: Just tried with IE. It did not attempt to restore state. I do not have Chrome installed.